# How to call backend Python script from Android

Tags: android, python, flask

**background:**

I have scenario where I have an Android app running on client and communicating with a PHP server.

**question:**

I want to run one Python script from the server, so I first tried calling Python from PHP like follows:

```
$output = passthru("mypy.py ".$var1." ".$var2);
```

When I just run PHP file it works.

But when I call it from Android the incoming request is too slow. I don't know is that Python script is executing (I am still testing this), but I know this is a very bad method of doing this.

I Googled and found that I have to use Django or Flask. But I just have one Python script which I have to run. How do I call one Python script from Android client?

Comment: More elaboration needed. How are you calling the php script, is it a HTTP call? If so how. Some code would also be helpful

Comment: yes its http POST call I am using volley library

Answer (score 1):

I finally found solution to my problem using [Flask](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_http_methods.htm)

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/success/<name>')
def success(name):
    return 'welcome %s' % name

@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))
    else:
        user = request.args.get('nm')
        return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

and I just make a http call on http://my_machine_ip:port_no/login from android using volley 
and it's work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

At Last I Solved my Problem. But using a technology service that is ngrok. I suggest everyone facing a problem similar to this must try ngrok

At least watch one video and consult from its documentation it is very easy!!!! believe me.....I think it take time not more than 10 minute